# How to retrieve table names in a mysql database with Python and MySQLdb?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I have an SQL database and am wondering what command you use to just get a list of the table names within that database.

Comment: just wondering why I got the down vote? I know the question was a newbie question but I thought that those type of questions were allowed on stack over flow?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

SHOW tables

15 chars

Answer (score 86):

To be a bit more complete:

```
import MySQLdb

connection = MySQLdb.connect(
                host = 'localhost',
                user = 'myself',
                passwd = 'mysecret')  # create the connection

cursor = connection.cursor()     # get the cursor


cursor.execute("USE mydatabase") # select the database

cursor.execute("SHOW TABLES")    # execute 'SHOW TABLES' (but data is not returned)
```

now there are two options:

```
tables = cursor.fetchall()       # return data from last query
```

or iterate over the cursor:

```
 for (table_name,) in cursor:
        print(table_name)
```

Comment: Pitty... they removed the whole website. So I removed the link, thanks for noting.

Comment: Error syntax error at or near "USE"
LINE 1: USE portal

Comment: fantastic answer

Comment: Thank you!! When we query and want to result do we always need to use fetchall() ?

Answer (score 7):

`show tables` will help. [Here is the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-tables.html).

Answer (score 4):

It is also possible to obtain tables from a specific scheme with execute the  single query with the driver below.

```sh
python3 -m pip install PyMySQL
```

```py
import pymysql

# Connect to the database
conn = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1',user='root',passwd='root',db='my_database')

# Create a Cursor object
cur = conn.cursor()

# Execute the query: To get the name of the tables from a specific database
# replace only the my_database with the name of your database
cur.execute("SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'my_database'")

# Read and print tables
for table in [tables[0] for tables in cur.fetchall()]:
    print(table)
```

output:

```sh
my_table_name_1
my_table_name_2
my_table_name_3
...
my_table_name_x
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another answer using the `sqlalchemy` and `pandas` libraries

```js
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd

# Make connection to server
def connect(self):  
    # create sqlalchemy engine
    engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://{user}:{pw}@{server}/{db}"
            .format(user=self.username,
            pw=self.password,
            server=self.server,
            db=self.database))
    return engine   

if _name_ == '_main_':
    server = 'myserver'
    database = 'mydatabase'
    username = 'myusername'
    password = 'mypassword'
    table = 'mytable'

    con = connect()
    my_query = f"SHOW COLUMNS FROM {table};"
    df = pd.read_sql_query(sql=my_query, con=con)
```