# Get items from a database tuple in Python

Tags: python, mysql, database, tuples, pymysql

This is my code:

```
import pymysql

def connect():
    print("connect to database")
    pw = input("Password: ")
    conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', port=3306, 
                           user='root', passwd=pw, db='contacts')
    conn.autocommit(True)
    cur_ = conn.cursor()
    return cur_

def show_tables(self):
    print("show tables: ")
    self.execute("""SHOW TABLES""")
    print(self.fetchall())
    return self.fetchall()

db = connect()
table_names = show_tables(db)  # returns a tuple
print(len(table_names))  # output zero
table_name = table_names[0][0]  # ? - todo - get item from tuple
```

`show_tables()` return the value `(('person',),)`.
I want to get the name `person` with `table_names[0][0]`. But this doesn't work. Also the length of `(('person',),)` is 0. But why?

Edit:
I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kame/Dropbox/code/python/scripts/database.py", line 65, in <module>
    table_name = table_names[0][0]  # ? - todo - get item from tuple
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Comment: You say "this doesn't work". What actually happens?

Comment: Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8363828/771848) help?

Comment: If I do `p = (('person',),)` and then `len(p)`, I get `1` as expected.  `p[0][0]` also gives `'person'` (again, as expected).  Are you sure you're returning the tuple you think you're returning?

Comment: I will post the whole code!

Comment: show us what table_names actually is, not what you're thinking it should be.

Comment: I allready showed this. It is `(('person',),)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like *show_tables(self)* is returning ***null***, a list on *None* object, because you can only call one time cursor.fetchall().

**The solution** : comment the line

```
print(self.fetchall())
```